# Change the CSS of the Customizer API

Tags: php, theme-customizer, api

Heyo,

I want to make the `Customizer` of my `Theme` look a bit different than usual. For example I want to make the `width` to `400px` instead of `300px`. Is there a way I can include custom-CSS for that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely, you can use the [customize_controls_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/customize_controls_enqueue_scripts/) hook to load custom CSS and JS.

This is an example of making the panel 400px:

File: **sample-theme/css/customizer-controls.css**

```
.wp-full-overlay.expanded {
    margin-left: 400px;
}
.wp-full-overlay-sidebar {
    min-width: 400px;
}
.wp-full-overlay.collapsed .wp-full-overlay-sidebar {
    margin-left: -400px;
}
```

File: **sample-theme/functions.php**

```
/**
 * Enqueue style for customized customizer.
 */
 function sample_theme_customize_enqueue() {
     wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-customize', get_theme_file_uri( 'css/sample-theme-customizer-controls.css' ) );
 }

 add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', 'sample_theme_customize_enqueue' );
```

Comment: @Pelle2010 Beware that the width of the Customizer pane will likely become variable in the future, and it already is today. Take note of https://make.wordpress.org/core/2017/05/16/customizer-sidebar-width-is-now-variable/